# Quick sort method is giving me a stackoverflowerror?

Tags: java

I have a quick sort method  which sorts elements in ascenidng order  but seem to keep getting a stackoverflowerror.

For some reason it is showing the error on the while loop, when the logic makes sense to me.
Here is the code for the quick sort class:

```
    public T[] sort(T[] arr, int left, int right)
    {

        int l = left;
        int r = right;

        if (right <= left)
            return null;

        //Find the pivot in the middle
        T pivot = arr[(left + (right - left)) / 2];

        T temp;


        while (l <= r)
        {
            // check values on left are bigger than the pivot
            while (arr[l].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
            {
                l++;
            }
            // check if values are smaller than the pivot
            while (arr[r].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
            {
                r--;
            }

            // l and r have gone past each other swap them
            if (l <= r)
            {
                //swap process
                temp = arr[l];
                arr[l] = arr[r];
                arr[r] = temp;

                // left pointer goes up 1
                // right pointer goes down 1
                l++;
                r--;
            }
        }

        if (left < r)
            sort(arr, left, r);
        if (l < right)
            sort(arr, l, right);
            return arr;
    }
```

The error seems to be pointing to

```
//Find the pivot in the middle
    T pivot = arr[(left + (right - left)) / 2];
```

I then seem to be getting many occuring errors.

Comment: This doesn't look quite like a proper quick sort, but maybe I'm missing something. There's a good article here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: Notice that you wrote (left + (right - left)) that is equal to right. I don't know if you did it intentionally or if it's an error

Comment: For future reference, read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are calculating Pivot incorrectly
    You should use T pivot = arr[left + (right - left) / 2];
    Below is working quick sort program using middle element as pivot:

```
public void quickSort(T arr[],int left, int right){
        int low =left, high = right;
        int pivot = arr[left + (right - left) / 2];

        while(low<=high){
            while (arr[low] < pivot) {
                low++;
            }

            while (arr[high] > pivot) {
                high--;
            }

            if (low <= high) {
                int  temp = arr[low];
                arr[low] = arr[high];
                arr[high] = temp;

                low++;
                high--;
            }

            if (left < high) {
                quickSort(arr,left, high);
            }

            if (low < high) {
                quickSort(arr,low, right);
            }
      }
}
```

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Stream API way:

```
T[] result = Arrays.stream(a)
                .skip(left)
                .limit(right - left)
                .sorted((o1, o2) -> {{you logic of comparing}})
                .toArray(String[]::new);
```

the difference in what you get only sorted part of an array. So you should concatenate them after if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in that line, yes. `T pivot = arr[(left + (right - left)) / 2];`
Due to the extra parentheses, everything is divided by 2. It should be

```
T pivot = arr[left + (right - left) / 2];
```

A couple stylistical remarks:

- as this is an in-place sort, returning `T[]` is not really necessary
- `T temp` could be moved into the swap-block

Putting it together:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class QuickSort<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    public void sort (T[] arr)
    {
        if (arr == null || arr.length <= 1)
            return;

        sort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }
    public void sort(T[] arr, int left, int right)
    {
        int l = left;
        int r = right;

        if (right <= left)
            return;

        //Find the pivot in the middle
        T pivot = arr[(left + (right - left)/2)];

        while (l <= r)
        {
            // check values on left are bigger than the pivot
            while (arr[l].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
            {
                l++;
            }
            // check if values are smaller than the pivot
            while (arr[r].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
            {
                r--;
            }

            // l and r have gone past each other swap them
            if (l <= r)
            {
                //swap process
                T temp = arr[l];
                arr[l] = arr[r];
                arr[r] = temp;

                // left pointer goes up 1
                // right pointer goes down 1
                l++;
                r--;
            }
        }

        if (left < r)
            sort(arr, left, r);
        if (l < right)
            sort(arr, l, right);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Integer[] numbers=new Integer[] {3,2,5,4,1};
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(numbers));
        new QuickSort<Integer>().sort(numbers);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(numbers));
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> [3, 2, 5, 4, 1]
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ```